# Pandas deleting duplicates by group efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

Given a data frame:

```
id  day  value
01  4    abc
01  3    abc
01  2    y
01  1    y
02  3    abc
02  2    x
02  1    x
03  4    abc
03  3    abc
03  2    abc
03  1    z
```

I want to remove rows with "abc" as duplicate and keep last.  The result would be:

```
id  day  value
01  3    abc
01  2    y
01  1    y
02  3    abc
02  2    x
02  1    x
03  2    abc
03  1    z
```

As of right now, I'm able to do this but the method I used is somewhat complicated.  I pull out all the rows with "abc" on to another data frame then remove duplicate keep last then concat the 2 data frames together.
Is there a simpler approach? Many thanks!

Comment: According to your desired output, it seems like you are keeping last, not first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way which should be efficient. Note I keep last, in line with your desired output.

```
res = pd.concat([df[df['value']=='abc'].drop_duplicates('id', keep='last'),
                 df[df['value']!='abc']]).sort_index()

#     id  day value
# 1    1    3   abc
# 2    1    2     y
# 3    1    1     y
# 4    2    3   abc
# 5    2    2     x
# 6    2    1     x
# 9    3    2   abc
# 10   3    1     z
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work. There might be a nicer way to avoid the sort at the end.

```
df_abc = df[df.value=='abc'].drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
df_not_abc = df[df.value!='abc']
df2 = pd.concat([df_abc, df_not_abc]).sort_values(by=['id', 'day'], 
    ascending=[True, False])
```